# How to show a div that has a class matching an attribute of the cliked element?

Tags: jquery

I am working on an interactive SVG world map. Each country has an attribute called data-code with a country code as its value. E.g.: 
Russia: `<path data-code="RU"></path>`
Japan `<path data-code="JP"></path>`
France `<path data-code="FR"></path>`

Whenever I click on a country, I want a hidden div containing information to fade in. That div has a class corresponding to the country code. E.g.:

```
<div class="RU"></div>
<div class="JP"></div>
<div class="FR"></div>
```

I wrote the code below that just does that:

```
$('path[data-code=RU"]').click(function() {
   $(".RU").fadeIn();
});
$('path[data-code="JP"]').click(function() {
   $(".JP").fadeIn();
}); 
$('path[data-code="FR"]').click(function() {
   $(".FR").fadeIn();
});
```

However, I want to avoid writing such code for every single country. Is there a way, that whenever I click on a country, the div with the matching country code will show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to attach event handlers and get the target element using the attribute value which can be fetched by [`.data('key')`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method

```
$('path[data-code]').click(function() {
   $("." + $(this).data('code')).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the click to all elements that have the data-code attribute. And then inside the click function you can get the corresponding country.

```
$('path[data-code]').click(function() {
  let country = $(this).data('code');
  $('path[data-code]').fadeOut(); // Here i added a way to fade out already active items
  $('.' + country).fadeIn();
});
```